# "get" or "is" regarding the future

Tags: grammar, future

Which of the following would be correct? Is it a question of dialect?

- "If this question gets answered, ..."
- "If this question is answered, ..."

(Inspired by [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12770/if-gets-outlawed-only-outlaws-will/12789#12789).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I offered my correction to Tim because, in the question in question, the implication in "if guns *get* outlawed..." is that some external agency (malign in this case) would be required for change to be effected.  "If guns *are* outlawed..." seems much more value-neutral to me. I accept that the difference is subtle, but I believe it's there -my ear and kiamaluno's graph say as much to me.

Answer (score 1):

Either one is fine. Functionally there is no difference between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Both the phrases are understood to have the same or similar meaning; *to get an answer* means *to obtain an answer*.

Looking at which phrase between *gets answered*, *gets an answer*, and *is answered* is the most used in American English, I obtain the [following data](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=gets+answered%2Cis+answered%2C+gets+an+answer&year_start=1970&year_end=2008&corpus=5&smoothing=0):

[image: first chart]

Comment: The problem with this comparison is that "is answered" shows up in two situations.  One is when it is the passive form of "answer" — the act of answering. The other is when "answered" is a past participle, and you are expressing a completed act: "the phone is answered already".  "Gets answered" can only show up as an alternative to the passive (the first situation) and can't be used in the second situation.  So while I don't doubt that the "is"-version is more common, this chart may overstate the extent to which they differ.

Comment: *The phone is answered already* would not be a common construct, although *the question is answered already* might be in some dialects. A much more likely construct for either would use *has been*: *the question has been answered already*.

Comment: Or "The question is answered in Bloggs, chapter 5".

Comment: I know that _is answered_ catches two different situations, but also searching for _the question is answered_ would catch two different situations (it could be part of _the question is answered by me_).